# Calculation in attribute table field - ArcGIS Desktop 10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm new to the Python language, and I need to add an "L-" character in the highlighted 'Teste' field in ArcGIS.

I tried the replace function, but it didn't work.

How do I do that?

example:
I want to appear 'L-8950099', 'L-8949941'...

[image]

Comment: teste is a text/string field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String Concatenation is what you are going for. The ArcMap window provides a few options for this:

#### [VB-Script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/concatenation-operators)

[image]

#### [Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp)

[image]

Comment: You missed the Calculate Field syntax for a column name reference. I'd use `"L-{:s}".format(!teste!)`

Comment: Sure did, @Vince! Thanks for the heads up. Hope the edits clarify.

Comment: Hi!! Thanks a lot for the help!! in the case of concatenation it worked.